# Google Maps Bounce Animation on Marker for a limited period

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I wish that a marker bounces for a few seconds and eventually stops automatically.. I am trying this code :

```
1. globalMarkers[i].setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
2. setTimeout(function() {
3.    globalMarkers[i].setAnimation(null)
4. }, 3000);
```

but for some reason, line 1 executes (hence marker will start bouncing) but the 3rd line returns the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setAnimation' of undefined
        (anonymous function)
```

Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: could you post some more code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works fine (with a single global marker object)

```
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);

    setTimeout(function() {
        marker.setAnimation(null)
    }, 3000);
```

My guess is that you're interating, and your setTimeout i is not in scope. Try this instead:

```
    for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        var marker = markers[x];
        marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
        stopAnimation(marker);
    }


function stopAnimation(marker) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        marker.setAnimation(null);
    }, 3000);
}
```

There are some more creative solutions here:

[Javascript how to use setTimeout on an iterative list operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8108346/javascript-how-to-use-settimeout-on-an-iterative-list-operation)